# ERROR exec.DDLTask : java.lang.NoSuchMethod Error:

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, bigdata, sqoop

I was importing data from mysql to hive using sqoop:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATASET -username root -P --table MATCHES  --hive-import
```

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readerFor(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader;18/11/25
>   11:42:58 ERROR ql.Driver: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readerFor(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader;

Comment: Anyone who can help me in resolving this error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the jackson-databind jar in your hive lib directory.check it once

Comment: yes i have the jackson databind jar in the hive lib.

Comment: please check the  three jars should have same version jackson-core

jackson-databind

jackson-annotations